# Resetting stack from a different one then navigate with params using React-Navigation v5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

So having two stacks A & B, if I were to traverse through a bunch of different screens in BOTH stacks and I want to reset stack B from A and also navigate to the root of stack A while passing params to it as well. How would I go about doing this?

Here's what I tried:

```
props.navigation.dispatch(
  CommonActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    routes: [
      {
        name: "StackAScreenOne",
        params: { user: "John" }
      }
    ]
  })
)
```

This seems to reset the stack and redirect me to the screen on stack A BUT. I don't receive the params. I'm guessing it has something to do with scoping limited to the current stack.

Is it possible to send params to a different stack after resetting it?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem?